# How to change color of navigation bar (gesture mode)?

Tags: android

How do I change the color of this `Navigation Bar` (gesture mode)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the color of navigation bar like so:

```
val window: Window = this@MainActivity.window
window.navigationBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this@MainActivity, R.color.yourColor)
```

And you'll have to set your color in res/values/colors.xml:

```
<color name="yourColor">#0D0D0D</color>
```